# tensorflow linear or boosted trees training fails with "error parsing message"

Tags: python, tensorflow, parsing, classification

I am trying to run an example through TF 2.0 that is basically identical to the example here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/boosted_trees except for the facts that:

1. My array is larger, 63319 rows x 7330 cols instead of 627 rows and 9 cols
2. I have no categorical columns, just numeric ones
3. Many of my column names are fairly long (maybe 50 chars, not *that* long!)

As in the example, the data comes from a pandas dataframe, has an int label, etc.  There are no nan's or inf's in my data.

If I try to train either a linear classifier or a boosted trees classifier on my data, I eventually get

```
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

and the last file mentioned is

```
File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3211, in _as_graph_def
    graph.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(data))
```

Any ideas?  I'm seeing the same behavior on both Ubuntu 18.04 and MacOS 10.15.6.  Ubuntu is Python 3.6.9, TF 2.3.0, protobuf 3.13.0.  Mac is Python 3.8.3, TF 2.3.0, protobuf 3.12.3

There are things I can do to track this down, like gradually shrink my data set until the error goes away, change my column headings, etc, but they are all moderately painful and seem unlikely to produce useful information.

Thanks so much!

Full traceback of error (the formatting is somewhat unpleasant; I hope it's ok):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 349, in train  
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1175, in _train_model  
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1208, in _train_model_default  
    saving_listeners)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1507, in _train_with_estimator_spec  
    log_step_count_steps=log_step_count_steps) as mon_sess:  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 604, in MonitoredTrainingSession  
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1038, in __init__  
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 737, in __init__  
    h.begin()  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 563, in begin  
    self._summary_writer = SummaryWriterCache.get(self._checkpoint_dir)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer_cache.py", line 63, in get  
    logdir, graph=ops.get_default_graph())  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py", line 371, in __init__  
    super(FileWriter, self).__init__(event_writer, graph, graph_def)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py", line 84, in __init__  
    self.add_graph(graph=graph, graph_def=graph_def)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py", line 194, in add_graph  
    true_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3294, in as_graph_def  
    result, _ = self._as_graph_def(from_version, add_shapes)  
  File "/home/ginsberg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3211, in _as_graph_def  
    graph.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(data))  
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

and the code producing the error was simply est.train(train_input_fn,max_steps=100) just like in the example (with train_input_fn a copy of the example as well).  Array sizes as above; X is 63319 x 7330 and Y is 63319 x 1.

Comment: Can you add complete traceback of error, tried code as well as the shape of X and Y?

Comment: Ugly but done.  Just as on the example page, really.  The full trace is ugly but maybe it helps.

Comment: I've also run this with random inputs, and get the same crash with floats, but it works with ints!  The crash is during the building of the graph; there is plenty of memory on the machine in question and the GPU isn't used until the graph is built, so that's not an issue.

Comment: The code is still running on my end. The code that I posted was using float32 dtype.

Comment: The code you posted has x = ... dtype=np.int16 so the x values are random ints between 0 and 99 inclusive.  That works for me.  If the x values are floats, it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually all of then are converted into float32. See the part where feature_column was created. Unfortunately on my machine, I don't get any errors but it takes a long time to run and the kernel eventually dies.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the converstion to float32.  But I can tell you that if I use np.random.randint, the graph gets constructed ok (sounds like it was for you, as well).  If I use np.random.uniform (or my original, sad to say), the graph construction process dies.  Having floats in the data is obviously different than converting to floats in the feature columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220588/discussion-between-aniket-bote-and-matt-ginsberg).